# Firebase message not received by browser

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Django project in which I use Firebase cloud messaging to power up push notifications. Here is my code:

index.html

```
<script>
   var config = {
    // ...
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/static/firebase-messaging-sw.js').then((registration) => {
        messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
        messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
           console.log('Notification permission granted.');
           return messaging.getToken();
        }).then(function(token){
            $.post('/a_send_fcm_token/', {'fcm_token_web': token}); 
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log('Error ocurred');
        });
    });

    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
        console.log('Hoorah'); // does not work :(
    });

</script>
```

Because Django project layout has certain peculiarities, I use `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` function in the above code to change the default location of `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file which would otherwise be in the root directory of the project.

My `firebase-messaging-sw.js` looks like this:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase-messaging.js');
var config = {
               // ...
            };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

And finally, my Django view which posts message to FCM:

```
 headers = {'Authorization': "key=AAAA7oE3MjY:APA91bE_M....",
            'Content-type': 'application/json'}
 token = ...
 payload = json.dumps({"notification": {}, "token": token})
 r = requests.post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", data=payload, headers=headers)
 return True
```

It seems like I've implemented most of the stuff correctly because I succeed in obtaining token from FCM. But I can't grab the message in `messaging.onMessage()`. It just won't trigger.

So **the question** is:

Why doesn't my `messaging.onMessage()` work ?

Comment: You might need a header for content type: `Content-Type: application/json`. Also, if the posted keys and config data are your real values, you should edit the post to put in placeholders.

Comment: I don't know Django.  Isn't there some way to get the response status for `requests.post(...)` to see if it's successful?

Comment: The header word for content type is `Content-Type` not `CONTENT_TYPE` as [shown in this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#setting_notification_options_in_the_send_request).  Also, as an experiment, try sending a `notification` payload instead of `data`, as in the example.

Comment: Content type key is still wrong. Should be `Content-Type`.

Comment: Bob, I am using http (unstead of https). Could this be the reason ?

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan Hi, Did you get the solution for this ? I have done almost to the same point where, we are unable to receive message, the response is `{'multicast_ids': [8978120973261046058], 'success': 1, 'failure': 0, 'canonical_ids': 0, 'results': [{'message_id': 'https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/m/gAAAAABeV3pcaXBMbwtiR6Fus2tZxm74e9sxPzqsBHgA3JB4gHSzv_dr1xCobaYfCqsQcEkUzvDyhILdIUkinyk5EPAY2NKas52GVYU39LfVBvm9LbR4mVdEYFP0IL5M0Qzd5bKA-sWhOAbjkFSrI6aZY7tl-fWNejBznt4TbIqX5macttj1LlC0kaC2KTDtxMn9MkotgV4n'}], 'topic_message_id': None}`

Comment: I opted for my websockets :)